# How to define a named range using excel vba that includes some formula

Tags: excel, vba

I need to define a named range which includes a formula but I am getting errors every time. The errors include object requires, type mismatch, etc. 
Is there anyone who can help me with this?

basically A named range like NAME1 which refers to:

```
=INDEX(LFSLookup!$AC$3:$AC$2000,MATCH("NAME"&LFSSPA!$C$25,LFSLookup!$Z$3:$Z$2000,0))
```

I have tried the following code but didn`t work.

```
 Set IMAGE1Range = "=INDEX(LFSLookup!$AC$3:$AC$2000,MATCH(" & "NAME" & ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet1").Range("C25").Value & ",LFSLookup!$Z$3:$Z$2000,0))"
    IMAGE1 = "IMAGE1111"
    ThisWorkbook.Names.Add Name:=IMAGE1, RefersTo:=IMAGE1Range
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close. You can't `Set` a string variable, and you just need to double the double quotes within a string to yield a single double quote in the result.

```
Option Explicit

Sub DoTheNameThing()
    Dim IMAGE1Range As String
    Dim IMAGE1 As String

    IMAGE1Range = "=INDEX(LFSLookup!$AC$3:$AC$2000,MATCH(""NAME""&Sheet1!$C$25,LFSLookup!$Z$3:$Z$2000,0))"
    IMAGE1 = "IMAGE1111"

    ThisWorkbook.Names.Add Name:=IMAGE1, RefersTo:=IMAGE1Range
End Sub
```

Comment: Updated the code. As you change the value in Sheet1!C25, the IMAGE1111 name will return different results. It's looking for NAMExyz where xyz is whatever you input in C25.

Comment: Yes, it works. Try refreshing this page - I've edit the code maybe 4 times.